# GCC inline asm: constraint for direct memory reference

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I need GCC to produce a consistent set of instructions for inline asm, but one of the instructions I'm using is sometimes compiled two different ways:

```
__asm__ ("mov %1,%%rax;" \
         : \
         : "m"(ref) \
         : "%rax");
```

Compile #1:

```
mov 0x200894(%rip),%rax
```

Compile #2:

```
mov 0x200894(%rip),%rdx
mov (%rdx),%rax
```

I'm not sure what the reason is for the second version, but I don't want it. Is there a constraint to specify that a memory reference should only be direct, i.e., not via register?

---

Update:

This variation always produces the exact same instruction:

```
    __asm__ ("mov ref@GOTPCREL(%rip),%rax");
```

Compiles to:

```
mov 0x200910(%rip),%rax
```

Comment: The two sequences of instructions are not equivalent. In the first `0x200894(%rip)` contains the result directly, in the second `0x200894(%rip)` contains a pointer to the result. What is `ref`?  Does it have the same type in both instances? Is it pointer to a function or object that's exported from a DLL (which sometimes might have to be an indirect reference through a 'GOT')?

Comment: It's `extern const char *ref`, and the second version does only occur in a shared library--so it must have a GOT reference even though the variable is defined inside the library. Can I avoid that somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure. There's a good description of the GOT mechanism here: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/  If there is a way to do what you want, that article might give you a clue (or a starting point) for how.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: thanks, I found a way (see update).

Comment: Byron, you should post your solution as an answer to your own question.  That was an interesting one.

Answer (score 3):

*Answering my own question:*

This variation always produces the exact same instruction:

```
__asm__ ("mov ref@GOTPCREL(%rip),%rax");
```

Compiles to:

```
mov 0x200910(%rip),%rax
```

For x86 where RIP-relative is not available, it takes two instructions:

```
__asm__ ("mov $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_,%%eax; \
          add ref@GOT,%%eax;");
```

Compiles to:

```
mov $0x2ff7,%eax
add 0xfffffff0,%eax
```

Two more instructions are required to make `%eax` RIP-relative, but I'm working in a binary translator where that's easier to do internally.